# ¿Es posible definir una política para nombrar restricciones en Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Se que es posible nombrar las `Foreing Keys` y también definir manualmente las restricciones, pero ¿No habrá alguna forma de definir una política de nomenclatura para cada tipo de restricción y evitar así los identificadores aleatorios que genera por defecto Spring?

***e.g.*** para una restricción de tipo `UNIQUE`, Spring genera el siguiente nombre: `UK_ob8kqyqqgmefl0aco34akdtpe` pero no se si sea posible definir de alguna forma el siguiente patrón: `AK_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE` para que Spring lo utilice cada que genere ese tipo de restricciones.

Lo anterior mas que nada para estandarizar las restricciones y facilitar su mantenimiento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentas, existe `@javax.persistence.ForeignKey`:

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicleId", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "Fk_userdetails_vehicle"))
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

Pero si quieres es cambiar la extrategia de nombres en general, he encontrado esto:[org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/)

Esta clase te permite definir el nombre de los elementos de tu base de datos, desde el nombre de las tablas, columnas hasta las foreign keys. Realmente es una extensión de la implementación de [hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.html):

Comment: Excelente! Justo lo que estaba buscando, por el momento logré definir un patrón para la restricciones `UNIQUE` declaradas a nivel de Tabla, muchas gracias.